# I can not understand the output of patsubst in a makefile

Tags: function, makefile, output, gnu-make, substitution

This is the guilty makefile :

```
$ cat -n example.mak
     1  define this
     2          $(patsubst $(1)/%.o,%.o,why_this_does/that.o)
     3          $(patsubst butnot/%.o,%.o, butnot/but_not_that.o)
     4  endef
     5
     6  why:
     7          $(info $(call this, why_this_does) ?)
```

And this is my question :

```
$ make -f example.mak 
        why_this_does/that.o
        but_not_that.o ?
make: 'why' is up to date.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is not in `patsubst` but in `call`.  [The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function) has a note:

> A final caution: be careful when adding whitespace to the arguments to call. As with other functions, any whitespace contained in the second and subsequent arguments is kept; this can cause strange effects. It’s generally safest to remove all extraneous whitespace when providing parameters to call.

and indeed, if you replace

```
$(info $(call this, why_this_does) ?)
```

by

```
$(info $(call this,why_this_does) ?)
```

you get what you want.

Comment: @Dadam42, whitespaces in Makefiles is always tricky.  They are usually word separators, which can be a pain when you want a space somewhere, and then they come from nowhere and hit you.